# MaterialAlertDialogBuilder crashes on custom view editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, illegalstateexception, material-dialog

The AlertDialog(Material) crashes when tries to read the editText content.

The AlertDialog:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(activity)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setView(R.layout.dialog_settings_entry)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_change)) { dialog, which ->
                etUserInput.hint = message
                sgr = etUserInput.text.toString() // << crashes here
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .show()
```

On clicking the positive button results as follows:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: etUserInput must not be null
        at com.home.profile.SettingsFragment$buildAlertDialog$1.onClick(SettingsFragment.kt:332)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
```

The **etUserInput** is simple editText in a seperate layout.
Unsure the crash reason. Would appreciate any insight into it or any helpful Material samples.

Comment: Where you initialize the EditText `etUserInput`? I think you forget to initialize it

Comment: I am guessing that's kotlin syntetics? If so, is the view which contains the `etUserInput` inflated in the current screen?

Comment: Yes, `etUserInput` inflated via Kotlin synthetic import.

Comment: Even let approach tried, `etUserInput.text?.let{ sgr = it.toString() }` but no luck!

Answer (score 7):

Cast the `DialogInterface` to an `AlertDialog` and then use `findViewById`.

Kotlin:

```
val et = (dialog as? AlertDialog)?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etUserInput)
val text = et?.text.toString()
```

--

Java:

```
EditText et = ((AlertDialog)dialog).findViewById(R.id.etUserInput);
String text = et.getText().toString();
```

--

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(activity)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setView(R.layout.dialog_settings_entry)
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.text_change)) { dialog, which ->
                val text = (dialog as? AlertDialog)?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etUserInput)?.text?.toString()

                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .setNegativeButton(getString(android.R.string.cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            .show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Work for me**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_shopin,null);
        RecyclerView rvCarrito = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.rvCarrito);
        rvCarrito.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rvCarrito.setLayoutParams(lp);
        rvCarrito.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        CarritoAdapter adapterCarrito = new CarritoAdapter(getActivity(),listProductDetalle);
        rvCarrito.setAdapter(adapterCarrito);
        new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getActivity())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setView(dialogView)
                .setPositiveButton("Ordenar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cerrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .show();
```